# Не заполняет dataGridView из класса

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть класс `Func.cs`, в нем функция:

```
public static void LoadTable(string table)
{
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("----------------------------"))
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();

            string sql = String.Format("SELECT * FROM `{0}`", table);

            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con))
            {
                using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);

                        Form2 f = new Form2();
                        f.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

`LoadTable` вызываю так:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Func.LoadTable("proverka");
}
```

В итоге, в dataGridView данные не добавляет.

Если вынести эту функцию из класса, то она работает.

Comment: Не понял этого:"Вызываю эту функцию в конструкторе Form2 так: Func.LoadTable("proverka");, но dataGridView не заполняется, а если вставить эту функцию в конструктор и там же вызывать, то работает." Какое=то масло масленое... Ты говоришь, что вызываешь ее в конструкторе, но не работает, вставляешь в конструктор и работает. Это разве не ождно и тоже?

Comment: @iluxa1810, извините, я не правильно выразился. Я имел ввиду что, если функцию LoadTable вызывать вне класса, то она работает, а если через класс - не работает. :)

Comment: using (DataTable dt = new DataTable()) - вот здесь using не нужно использовать, потому что dt передается  в   DataGridView как источник данных. Следовательно, ее еще рано уничтожать.

Comment: А зачем вы внутри using создаете форму? Мне кажется, что объект тут же умирает после создания запросов.

Comment: Внесите правку в вопрос, откуда что вызываете. Можно с описанием места(класса). Тогда будет Вам ответ. А так получается *масло масляное*, Вам уже это написали

Comment: @iluxa1810, попробовал убрать юзинги - безрезультатно. А может дело в том, что я не правильно передаю в dgv? То есть, у меня в данный момент рабочая форма - Form2, а я в неё так передаю:
Form2 f = new Form2();
f.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: в общем дело обстоит так: если Вы находитесь в Form2 - то она у Вас уже есть и Вы можете писать так: `this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;`. Если у Вас есть класс, в котором Вы хотите что-то сделать, то во время его инициализации передайте туда форму и делайте что нужно...просто Вы не достаточно предоставили кода, мы тут как-бы сейчас просто гадаем.

Comment: @Максим, Я бы в дебагере прошелся по этому месту. 1) Убедился бы, что на новой форме успешно проходит метод инициализации компонентов, а потом бы перепроверил присваемую таблицу.

Comment: У меня this недоступен в классе о_О. Спасибо за советы, буду что-то пробовать.

Comment: посмотрите ответ, который я Вам дал. В нем описано, как можно решить Ваш вопрос.

Comment: @Denis Bubnov, сижу, смотрю, мало что понимаю :) Пожалуйста, если вас не затруднит, приведите пример "то во время его инициализации передайте туда форму и делайте что нужно".

Comment: @Максим, не комментарий, а ответ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А передайте в Ваш класс форму `Form2`, вот так:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Func.LoadTable(this, "proverka");
}
```

Зайдите в дизайнер формы `Form2.Designer.cs`, найдите там строку:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView  dataGridView1;
```

Поменяйте модификатор доступа с `private` на `public` - это позволит обратиться к компоненту вне формы. (но так делать не рекомендуется). Дизайнер формы найти можно вот так (только у Вас нужно это сделать для `Form2` согласно Вашему вопросу):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем поправьте Ваш метод:

```
public static void LoadTable(Form2 form, string table)
{
// Ваш код... 
    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
    {
         sda.Fill(dt);
         form.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    } 
// Ваш код...
}
```

Не знаю, как у Вас `Func` создается...ну да ладно.

Comment: Спасибо! Выручили! И да, модификатор public у меня стоял на dgv, так что, дело значит было в том, что неправильно передавал данные из класса. Спасибо! =)

Comment: @Максим, обратите внимание на то, что так делать не рекомендуется. В смысле делать открытыми компоненты формы. Но если очень нужно, то... )